# AlexNet works fine on web images but not on mobile images

Tags: android, deep-learning

I have trained a deep-learning model using alexNet to classify car models. The data was collected from the web,including google image, flicker,.. etc.

The model was tested on a separate test set collected from the web 'many comes from flicker', and it works fine. However, I have build a simple android app, that takes a photo 'with landscape mode' and send it to the server to recognize the car. The performance on the mobile images are very poor. I have tested the images with the alexNet model trained on imageNet and the model didn't answer correctly these images.

I wonder, if there is any think i missed when applying mobile images.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is: why could a model works fine on web images, while be very bad on mobile taken images? Is there any normalization or preprocessing that should be done to get the model works on mobile images as well? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add photos taken with a mobile device to your training data. If this is not possible maybe you can preprocess the image in a way to make it more like the images used for training (e.g. normalization).

Edit:

mean-image subtraction is not normalization. Normalization is subtracting the mean image and then dividing by the standard deviation. Both computed from the training set.

You should analyze both images. Maybe there are resolution / lightning changes etc. Without having a sample of both images it is hard to tell what exactly the difference is. However deep learning is notorious to being bad with changes in data acquisition.

2nd Edit:

Another point that might fail on mobile images is the resolution. CNN work on any resolution and if you pass in a 4000x2000 image to an imagenet it will probably find something different than on an 224x224 image. For this reason you might want to post a web image and a mobile image and we on stackoverflow might be able to tell you the difference.

Comment: I dont know what kind of preprocessing should i apply. 
I did use the normalization by the mean-image (computed from the training set). thanks for help.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect changes.